# How do I view a series into table form in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to view a series in a table form like this:

test:

```
SYM               ABC
PRICE             NaN
HD1               NaN    
HD2               100
BD1               12
BD2               10
SZ1               20
Name: 2014-03-13 00:30:01.643000, dtype: object
```

I want to be able to view it as this:

test:

```
                            SYM  PRICE  HD1  HD2  BD1  BD2  SZ1
TS                             
2014-03-13 00:30:01.643000  ABC  NaN    NaN  100  12   10   20
```

Sorry should I have added the code. I attempted to do it this way creating a function:

```
def trans (datafrm):
    tempmx = 0
    tempmx = pd.DataFrame.as_matrix(datafrm)
    return tempmx
```

Thinking that trying to convert it to a matrix might change the view. It threw a TypeError instead.
To add, the series came from pulling out a row from a larger dataframe.

Comment: could you give some code, please? cf http://sscce.org

Comment: lets see what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi sorry, should have added it:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would probably convert it to a dataframe with the `to_frame` method and then transpose it (example, using a slighty different series):

```
>>> print s

close         187.56
high          187.73
low           187.54
open          187.70
volume    1922600.00
Name: 2014-05-09 00:00:00, dtype: float64

>>> print s.to_frame().T

             close    high     low   open   volume
2014-05-09  187.56  187.73  187.54  187.7  1922600
```